# Multiple Spring Data modules found - with JPARepository and no Mongo in the project

Tags: spring

In my Spring boot project, there's no notion of MongoDB.

The Repositories extend `JPARepository` instead of `CrudRepository` to avoid confusion:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Expense, Long> {
    public Car findById(long id);
}
```

There is nothing in my `build.gradle` that may sound like a Spring Data module:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'

group = 'com.boot'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = """my-proj"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

test{

    forkEvery = 1
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}

repositories {
     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version:'5.1.44'
    compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version:'3.18.0-GA'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version:'2.0.14.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version:'0.7.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-cas', version:'4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-acl', version:'4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'bsf', name: 'bsf', version:'2.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-batch', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-ldap', version:'4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'javax.jdo', name: 'jdo-api', version:'3.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-core', version:'4.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'springloaded', version:'1.2.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib', version:'1.0.6'
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version:'2.11.0'
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version:'1.6'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version:'2.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jersey', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version:'0.7.5'
    compile(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version:'4.5.3') {
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version:'3.4'
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE') {
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate', name: 'jetty-all', version:'9.2.13.v20150730'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version:'1.4.196'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-test', version:'4.3.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version:'4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-core', version:'1.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.sleepycat', name: 'je', version:'5.0.73'
    compile group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version:'1.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'4.3.12.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version:'1.13.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.hateoas', name: 'spring-hateoas', version:'0.23.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-rest-core', version:'2.6.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.plugin', name: 'spring-plugin-core', version:'1.2.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version:'4.3.12.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.11'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version:'4.3.12.RELEASE'
}
```

And the entities are annotated with `@Entity` and there is no `@Document` anywhere in my project:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Car")
public class Car implements Serializable {
    ....
```

I'm wondering why Spring is still confused:

```
factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]]
2017-11-26 07:57:54.347  INFO 296 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
```

Note: This only happens on Heroku server. It works fine on my local when I build it in eclipse.